# Multi module maven project dependency issue with jpa

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error with a multi-module maven project.
I attempt to run "maven install" via eclipse run as option.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mysite-entities 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mysite-entities ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/thomas/spring/mysite-parent/mysite-entities/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mysite-entities ---
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /home/thomas/spring/mysite-parent/mysite-entities/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/thomas/spring/mysite-parent/mysite-entities/src/main/java/com/mysite/entities/Mcc.java:[5,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/thomas/spring/mysite-parent/mysite-entities/src/main/java/com/mysite/entities/Mcc.java:[6,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/thomas/spring/mysite-parent/mysite-entities/src/main/java/com/mysite/entities/Mcc.java:[8,1] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Entity
@Entity
```

Mcc.java:

```
package com.mysite.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Mcc implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4146710247449711520L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml includes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've checked the maven dependencies that are pulled in and they include hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar which in turns includes all the necessary classes.

Why am I getting this maven error?

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` and the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? (Or at least the relevant parts - version numbers for example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a dependency for `javax.persistence`. This goes along with the JPA implementation (Hibernate in your case).

Add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this post somewhere and found this get rid of the warning messages.

Copy `slf4j-api-VERSION.jar` and `logback-classic-VERSION.jar` to `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext`

- `slf4j-api-VERSION.jar` is located in `%M2_REPOSITORY%\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\VERSION\`
- `logback-classic-VERSION.jar` is located in `%M2_REPOSITORY%\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\VERSION\`
- If not using logback-classic, then At least `slf4j-log4j12`, `slf4j-simple`, `slf4j-jdk14` or `logback-classic` binding must be in rhw classpath.